# Resource.Raw does not contain definition for a Json file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to read Json file for an Xamarin.Android project, but I'm receive the error when I'm trying build:

> error CS0117: 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Raw'

I already tried to delete the resource.designer.cs file, but it did not work.
Other folders working normal.

My code:

```
 public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
 {
    _Map = googleMap;
    _Map.SetOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    _Map.SetMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.LoadRawResourceStyle(this, Resource.Raw.styleJson));
 }
```

Tree view of a part of the Resources folder :

[image]

Is there something wrong with my implementation ?

Comment: Did you try to delete the `obj` and `bin` file in this project, then re-build this project.

Comment: If you delete the `obj` and `bin`,If it is not work, you can get details error with following ways ,Please click the Tools ->options->xamarin->android settings->xamarin Diagnostics->output verbosity->select details ; And click the Tools ->options->projects and solutions->build and run->MSBuild project build output verbosity ->select detailed    Then compile your project again and check the output window. It will tell you exactly what the problem is

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue?

Comment: Following below Steps 
1) Close your visual studio
2) clear your solution 
3) try to access this way Resource.Raw.styleJson

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue **Android.Resource.Raw.stylejson.json**, it should be just **Resource.Raw.stylejson.json** or **aaa.bbb.Droid.Resource.Raw.stylejson.json**

**stylejson.json** is within your app's namespace, not in the Android system.